# List.map returns an unexpected type

Tags: ocaml

I'm learning OCaml (OCaml 5.0.0).

I defined the function below.

```
let make_pair x ls = List.map (fun y -> (x,y)) ls;;
```

I expected `make_pair 1 ["a","b"];;` returns `[(1,"a");(1,"b")]`, but actually the function returns `(int * (string * string)) list = [(1, ("a", "b"))]`.

How do I solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You entered `["a","b"]`, which is a list consisting of a single pair, `("a","b")`. You need a semicolon instead of a comma: `["a";"b"]`.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to Sam Henke's very correct [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76345348/15261315), it may be instructive to reference OCaml's [documentation](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/index.html) on [precedence and associativity](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/expr.html#ss:precedence-and-associativity).

Viewing this, we can see that `,` has higher precedence than `;`, and both have lower precedence that things like mathematical operators and function application. The practical effect of this is:

```
# let f x = x * 2 in
  [f 3 + 1, 8; 8, 9];;
- : (int * int) list = [(7, 8); (8, 9)]
```

While possibly *convenient* and certainly valid, you may wish to disambiguate with parentheses.

```
# let f x = x * 2 in
  [(f 3 + 1, 8); (8, 9)];;
- : (int * int) list = [(7, 8); (8, 9)]
```

Note that this closely mirrors the formatting OCaml uses in printing the resulting tuple list. This is a likely indicator that you've made good use of parentheses.